# Организация очереди запросов через jQuery.Deferred()

Tags: jquery

По нажатию на кнопку идет post запрос, который возвращает html со скриптами, содержание которого зависит от параметров (param).

```
function GetPlaces(param) {
    $.post(places_url, param, function(data) {
        $(".places").html(data);
    });
}
```

При быстрой смене параметров и многократном нажатии на кнопку отрисовка выполняется естественно не порядке нажатия на кнопку. Нужно реализовать нечто вроде очереди (чтобы при повторном нажатии на кнопку отправка происходила, только после полной отрисовки и выполнения всех скриптов первого нажатия.

Пытаюсь сделать так, но желаемого результата нет:

```
defPlaces = $.Deferred();

function GetPlaces(param) {
    defPlaces = defPlaces.then(
        $.post(places_url, param, function(data) {
            $(".places").html(data);
        })
    );
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция, которую вы предложили, выглядит очень странно. Как минимум, отдавать важную часть управляющей конструкции с сервера при каждом запросе - неправильно.

В вашей исходной конструкции было три ошибки:

1. Вы не вызвали нигде метод `resolve` (по-хорошему, его надо было вызвать сразу же). Также для создания изначально заресолвленного промиза можно воспользоваться методом `when`.
2. Вы не передали в метод `then` функцию для обратного вызова.
3. Вы не ждете окончания выполнения запроса. Для того, чтобы промиз, используемый в качестве очереди, оказался заресолвлен только по окончанию запроса - надо вернуть этот самый запрос из колбека `then`.

Вот итоговый код:

```
defPlaces = $.when();

function GetPlaces(param) {
    defPlaces = defPlaces.then(function () {
        return $.post(places_url, param, function(data) {
            $(".places").html(data);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сработала следующая конструкция:

```
defPlaces = $.Deferred();

function GetPlaces(param) {
    defPlaces.done(function() { setPlaces(param); });
}

function setPlaces(param) {
    defPlaces = $.Deferred();
     $.post(places_url, param, function(data) {
        $(".places").html(data);
      });
}
```

В html, который возвращается в post, после выполнения всех скриптов добавить:

```
defPlaces.resolve();
```